# featuring the Smith Brothers of cough drop fame

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "cough drop fame" mean "fame that has the power of medicine that can stop your cough"?

> Steven Pinker tweeted:
>
> New Psych Science Lecture - Concepts and Reasoning, **featuring the Smith Brothers of cough drop fame** as an illustration of Wittgenstein on categories*, & an explanation of Bayes' Rule (yes, it will be on the exam). *Thanks to Lila & Henry Gleitman.

Comment: You might have had luck with googling "smith brothers cough drop", did you try that before posting your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase *NAME of NOUN fame* means *NAME, who is famous because of doing NOUN*, or *NAME, whom you might know because they did NOUN*.

So, in this case, "the Smith Brothers of cough drop fame" means *the Smith brothers, whose name you should recognize because they have something to do with cough drops.*

As a commentor pointed out, searching for "smith brothers cough drops" would have shown you that the Smith Brothers were William Wallace Smith I (1830–1913) and Andrew Smith (1836–1895).  They were the owners of *Smith Brothers Cough Drops*, which have been selling cough drops more or less continuously since 1852 ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_Brothers)).

But a phrase like "the Smith Brothers of cough drop fame" does not necessarily mean that the Smith Brothers sold cough drops.  They could be famous because of some other reason related to cough drops.

For example:

"Joe of bubble gum fame" would be [Bazooka Joe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazooka_Joe) who is famous for being a bubble gum mascot.

Here's one that's harder to understand, but is a pretty common kind of usage:

"IBM of 'golf ball' fame" ([The Guardian](https://www.newspapers.com/image/?clipping_id=30281612&fcfToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJmcmVlLXZpZXctaWQiOjI1OTU3MzA0OCwiaWF0IjoxNjE0NzUzMTM2LCJleHAiOjE2MTQ4Mzk1MzZ9.O4vqNN7hgYplI7aLc8JhFM3EnOqm6o1zmoC8Q8C6rWU)) means *the IBM corporation which is famous for designing electric type writers that use a "golf ball"* ([IBM Selectric typewriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Selectric_typewriter))

Answer (score 4):

No, "cough drop fame" does not refer to the power of the medicine.  It is providing extra context about [the Smith Brothers who are famous for their brand of cough drops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_Brothers).

From the [Lexico definition](https://www.lexico.com/definition/of_%E2%80%94_fame) for "Of _ Fame": *Having a particular famous association; famous for having or being.*

So in general, the subject of the fame would come first in the sentence followed by why they are famous.  Some alternative examples:

> Mojave Aerospace Ventures is funded by one of the most famous names in the computer world, **Paul Allen** of **Microsoft** fame.

Paul Allen is famous for having co-founded Microsoft.

> The show was screened around the world and starred **David Schwimmer** of **Friends** fame and British actor Damian Lewis.

David Schwimmer is famous as a cast member of the popular television show *Friends*.